# running a function on a column twice

Tags: t-sql

Lets suppose I have a DB. Lets call this database Utils. In `Utils` I have 2 functions. Okay lets say I am currently working in db `MyDatabase`. I need to calculate some fields in a table. This is how I currently do it: My select statement looks like the following

```
SELECT *, 
   column1= UTILS.dbo.Function1(ID)
   column2 =UTILS.dbo.Function1(Name
   column3 =UTILS.dbo.Function1(Address)
INTO ##temp_table1 
FROM MyDatabase.dbo.Customers


SELECT *, 
   column1= UTILS.dbo.Function2(ID)
   column2 =UTILS.dbo.Function2(Name
   column3 =UTILS.dbo.Function2(Address)
INTO ##temp_table2
FROM MyDatabase.dbo.Customers
```

The problem with this is that I don't just have 3 columns to be calcualted. I have about 100. So I really don't want to repeat the select statement twice because if a change comes along then I have to change it in two places which is error prone, makes my script very long and hard to read and other issues.

My solution

```
    USE Utils; GO;    
    DECLARE @strSQL VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @strSQL = '    
        SELECT *, 
               column1= UTILS.dbo.temp_function(ID)
               column2 =UTILS.dbo.temp_function(Name
               column3 =UTILS.dbo.temp_function(Address) '

    exec sp_rename 'UTILS.dbo.Function1' ,'temp_function'
    exec (@strSQL + 'into temp_table1 FROM Customers')
    exec sp_rename 'temp_function' ,'UTILS.dbo.Function1'

    exec sp_rename 'UTILS.dbo.Function2' ,'temp_function'
    exec (@strSQL + 'into temp_table2 FROM Customers')
    exec sp_rename 'temp_function' ,'UTILS.dbo.Function2'
```

But I dont like this solution since i Have to change databases to use `sp_rename`. It also gives me caution. And MSDN advises against it.

What is a good way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Seems to me like some light copy/paste work is needed whenever query 1 changes. Keeping "strong typing" against the database and object names is far better than 100 extra lines of code which seem pretty easy to maintain.

Comment: If this has to be done in the DB and not in the app tier with an auto-gen'ed set of classes like EF or LINQ to SQL, I think your best bet for ease of maintenance is to use the sys schema.  Without writing out the whole solution, you write a cursor that iterates over a query joining sys.columns to sys.tables and build up a string that you can exec() to get your results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily avoid using sp_rename by changing your solution as follows:

```
USE Utils; GO;    
DECLARE @strBaseSQL VARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@strSQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @strBaseSQL = '    
    SELECT *, 
           column1= UTILS.dbo.temp_function(ID)
           column2 =UTILS.dbo.temp_function(Name
           column3 =UTILS.dbo.temp_function(Address) '

SELECT @strSQL = REPLACE(@strBaseSQL, 'UTILS.dbo.temp_function', 'UTILS.dbo.function1')
EXEC (@strSQL + 'into temp_table1 FROM Customers')

SELECT @strSQL = REPLACE(@strBaseSQL, 'UTILS.dbo.temp_function', 'UTILS.dbo.function2')
EXEC (@strSQL + 'into temp_table2 FROM Customers')
```